# How to load database Application from PluginKit

Tags: ios, realm

I have Custom Keyboard app and using Realm database. But both pluginKit and application are not used the same database.

**Application:**

```
/Users/baotuan/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/A0C0F2B4-8A82-4CC3-9925-210FEB9A5590/data/Containers/Data/Application/F50606AD-37A2-48E1-A1F9-5B14522184C0/Documents/default.realm
```

**PluginKit**

```
/Users/baotuan/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/A0C0F2B4-8A82-4CC3-9925-210FEB9A5590/data/Containers/Data/PluginKitPlugin/1DACDBF8-AC2C-4204-A672-407A4060E803/Documents/default.realm
```

So how can i use the same database for my app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To share data between an application and an extension on iOS, you'll want to use [App Groups](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Miscellaneous/Reference/EntitlementKeyReference/Chapters/EnablingAppSandbox.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011195-CH4-SW19). App Groups provide a shared directory that can be accessed by any process that is a member of the group. [Andrea Mazzini](https://twitter.com/theandreamazz) has written a blog post about [sharing data between a WatchKit extension and an app](http://fancypixel.github.io/blog/2015/03/29/share-data-between-watchkit-and-your-app-with-realm/) which walks covers setting up an App Group.